# I want to popup each item to view and edit . How can I do this using modal with router in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, bootstrap-modal

Before deleting each holiday item in the list, I want to show a popup message asking if you want to delete it. When the user wants to delete any holiday item by pressing the delete button, I want it to prompt the user with a popup before deleting it.

Likewise, when the user wants to examine any holiday item in detail by pressing the view button, now it sends the user to a different page, instead, I want it to be shown to the user with a popup.

```
const AddHolidayForm = () => {
    const [holidays, setHolidays] = useState([])
    const [res, setRes] = useState([]);  //<-- state to render
    useEffect(() => {
        loadHoliday();
    }, []);
    const loadHoliday = async () => {      
        const res = await axios.post(`http://localhost:.....`, {           
        });

        setHolidays(res.data.reverse());
    };
    const deleteHoliday = async id => {
        await axios.delete(`http://....`);
        loadHoliday();
    };
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="py-4">                    
                <Table responsive>
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">#</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            <th scope="col">Name</th>
                            <th scope="col">Start Time</th>
                            <th scope="col">End Time</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {res.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage)
                                .map((holiday, index) => {
                                    return (
                                        <tr>
                                            <th scope="row">{index + 1}</th>
                                            <td> <Link class="btn btn-primary mr-2"
                                                to={`/holiday/view/${holiday.id}`}>
                                                <FaEye />
                                            </Link>
                                                 <Link
                                                    class="btn btn-danger"
                                                    onClick={() => deleteHoliday(holiday.id)}                 
                                                >                                                    
                                                    <FaTrashAlt />
                                                </Link></td>
                                            <td>{holiday.name}</td>
                                            <td>{holiday.startTime}</td>
                                            <td>{holiday.endTime}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    )  }) }
                    </tbody>
                </Table>                           
        </div>

    );
}

export default AddHolidayForm;
```

Comment: When user clicks delete show a modal by triggering a state update asking the user to confirm it that's it

Comment: You can use sweetalert2 for this. It provides all the requirements that you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use the `window.confirm` method. 
Someone above suggests `sweetalert2` that works similar to the `confirm` method but allows us to style the popup.

```
const deleteHoliday = async id => {
  const answer = confirm("Do you want to delete?")
  if (answer === false) return
  
  await axios.delete(`http://....`)
  loadHoliday()
}
```

Comment: const answer = window.confirm("Do you want to delete?") it worked this way. thanks.

Comment: Just in case, `window.confirm` and `confirm` it is the same thing.